# Receive udp data from the system udp server on android?

Tags: android

hi I am new to android.I need to know how to receive the udp data in android emulator.Data's are coming from the PC (UDP SERVER is running on the pc).I am using Eclipse IDE.Can anyone guide me to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set up [redirects](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#redirections) since the emulator sits behind a virtual router.

Start the emulator, connect to it via telnet, then give it routing commands;

```
telnet localhost 5554 
redir add udp:<host-port>:<guest-port>
```

You will need to this each time you restart the eumlator, so it might be worthwhile to script it.